# how to make a 301 redirect on windows server (IIs)

Tags: url, iis, redirect, url-rewriting

can you help me out pointing me how to make the 301 redirection from my desktop website to my mobile website using user agent. I know how to make it on apache server but we recently switch hosting to IIS...any help would be very appreciated.

thanks.

Gus

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps

1. Open Internet services manager, right click on the file or folder you
   wish to redirect (Here your website directory)
2. Select the radio titled "a redirection to a URL".
3. Enter the redirection page
4. Check "The exact url entered above" and
   the "A permanent redirection for this resource" 3
5. Click on 'Apply'

Comment: Thanks Vikram but that is not what I meant. I want to create a redirection that uses the user agent of the mobile systems (iphone, ios, ipad and android) to make the 301 redirect to the mobile.mysite.com